# Remove broken heatbreak

Tags: hotend, repair, e3d-hemera

I'm trying to replace my hotend with the E3D Hemera direct kit. I got to the final step of hot-tightening the hot side and managed to snap my heatbreak. The part that screws into the heat-sink is stuck, though I was able to remove it from the heater block section.

Below is a picture of the heatbreak. The red square shows what it in the heat-sink. It's mostly thread (with thermal compound) but a bit of the unthreaded metal is sticking out (above the disk shown).

I've tried removing it with a jeweler's drill (which is how I removed the heater block portion, but I cannot get a good grip on the long threaded piece. I've also tried pliers and rounded needle-nose pliers. Neither worked. I couldn't find my regular needle-nose and will go to the store to try that. Are there other options to break this free or am I stuck with buying a replacement heat-sink? I already ordered a replacement, but it'd be nice to have a backup in case something else goes awry (as has been the case with this modification; this is snafu number 4).

[image: Heatbreak with stuck portion highlighted]

Comment: Maybe you can add a photo how much is stuck in the radiator?

Comment: I can try when I get home. That's why I included the current picture. In the box only the unthreaded portion at the top is sticking out. (About 1/4 inch of metal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broken screws or screws with damaged screw heads are typically removed with screw extractors. Since there is already a hole you could "drill" (unscrew) it out with a screw extractor, as it is counter clockwise, it is about creating enough friction to unscrew it from the threads. Beware that it is not drilling and spalling material, turn slowly.

[image]

Alternatively, a grip vice pliers may work if there is enough "meat" to clamp on.

[image]

Comment: Never heard of the extractor before. Nifty. Are there any particulars that I should concern myself with? Namely the fact that there isn't much metal due to the aforementioned hole and what size of extractor I should purchase. Since the Hemera uses tight tolerances and came as a kit, should I remove the dual gear assembly?

Comment: I'm definitely googling how to use an extractor, but I doubt I'll find anything that is specific to 3D printers, asking so I don't miss anything that definitely won't be covered elsewhere.

Comment: @LuxClaridge It's all about creating enough friction to unscrew it, you could also fill it with hard wood and use a smaller extractor. Usually you buy them in a set with multiple sizes.